# Fermat's principle of least time for reflection and refraction

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics, variational-principle

In discussing geometrical optics, Fermat's principle of least time is often used to solve problems and is generally used as a replacement of laws of reflection and refraction.
Fermat's principle is usually presented as an intuitive idea, but I wish to find a way where we can show that is is actually a result of least of reflection and refraction.
We have explanation for laws of reflection and refraction and they must be the basic laws, with Fermat's principle being a consequence of it.
Do we have any explanation suggesting that Fermat's principle is the direct consequence of laws of reflection and refraction?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2041/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100317/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257140/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Sir, how my question is related to the one you mentioned, I wish to find a way to prove Fermat's principle using reflection and refraction.

Comment: Do you know the optical laws for reflection and refraction?